# The data insertion INSERT INTO not working in my php script

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, web

I have developed a software but suddenly got that the data insertion using INSERT INTO is not working. I dont know why it happened. Here is the code piece given below:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "booking";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if($conn->connect_error){die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);}

$sql = "INSERT INTO data (CNIC) VALUES ('37105458742-5')";


if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql) {echo("Success");}


?>
```

The database connection is successful. On the line 14 $sql = "INSERT..... gives error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\booking\index.php on line 14
```

Comment: it not a INSERT error. it is syntax error. Please read the error message carefully and then resolve it. Modify your last statement as : if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql) )
        {
    echo("Success");
    
        }

Comment: Also don't mix object oriented approach with procedural approach. It will not give error but not a good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use below code

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "success";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

and remove below line from your code

> if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql) {echo("Success");}

Answer (score 2):

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql) {echo("Success");}
```

Should be

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {echo("Success");}
```

Missing a closing bracket.

Comment: @ZeshanMuztar If the answer worked for you, shouldn't you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ending bracket of If condition:

**This:**

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql) {echo("Success");}
```

**Should be:**

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo("Success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your code as below:-

```
// You have Missed ')' bracket in below line
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo("Success");
}else{
  // Always check for errors
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Hope it will help you :)